# time series with different time range on the same plot result in ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (366,) (92,)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I thought this would have been straight forward using time series but apparently I was wrong.

I have a series with a daily frequency DateTimeIndex that is a subset of another time series, and I am trying to plot this against the other.

This is an example of what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt1 = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31', freq="D")
dt2 = pd.date_range(start='2020-05-01', end='2020-07-31', freq="D")

ts = pd.Series(range(len(dt2)), index=dt2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(dt1, ts)
```

And the error I get: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (366,) (92,)`

I understand the error, but does it mean I have to fill the shorter time series with nan so that the number of values match? I was hopingthat the DateTimeIndex could handle this automatically, but maybe I was wrong...

Comment: As noted in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html), **x**: 1d array of dimension N, and 
**y**: 2d array (dimension MxN), or sequence of 1d arrays (each dimension 1xN).

Comment: Oh I see... it's just for stackplot then... Ok, I'll find another way, thanks!

Comment: What about just using `ts = ts.reindex(dt1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`stackplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html) docs:

> **x**: 1d array of dimension N.
>
> **y**: 2d array (dimension MxN), or sequence of 1d arrays (each dimension 1xN).

Perhaps the easiest option here is to just `reindex` using the longer time series; this will automatically fill the missing dates with NaNs that won't be plotted.

```
ts = ts.reindex(dt1)
```